# Incorrect installation of Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.4

When I try to find the location of my python3 installation, this is what I get

```
08:48:07 >> which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin//python3
```

How do I move my python installation to /usr/local/bin/python3

Also if I try to reinstall python 3 using brew this is what I get

```
08:50:37 >> brew install python3
Warning: python3-3.4.1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I basically want to move my python installation to its natural location.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

should do the trick.